# MySQL database cluster vs. replication setup for large crawler indexes

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-cluster

What is the most efficient way to set up a MySQL cluster or replication in an application that has a crawler/indexing engine with thousands of read/writes and then a separate front-end for public access.

It is kind of like creating a mini Google search engine. The database that keeps the latest crawl data has to be separate in a way not to impact the performance of the publicly-accessed database. However, eventually the two databases need to be reconciled so that the publicly-accessed database has all the latest data.

So my idea would be the crawler DB would be the master, while the publicly accessed database would be the slave. And then edit/insert actions on the publicly assessed database would really need to be done on the master DB (same as crawler).

Is this the best way to do such a thing? Is there a better setup?

More information:

Currently there is a lot of reading/updating/inserting at a very fast pace while the crawler is running.

For example, the crawler could send 10 businesses with location and items for each business per every 2-3 seconds, at which, the receiving server needs to do the following. Search DB if business already exists (out of few hundred thousand records), if not create it. Then search if that location (out of half a million records) for that business exists, if not, create it. Then loop through each item of the business and check if it exists (out of 40+ million records), update, if not, create it. Old ones are backed up and then deleted.

Comment: Is the crawler single-threaded?  Or are there multiple being made into the database?

Comment: Which "MySQL Cluster" do you mean?  "InnoDB Cluster"?  "Galera Cluster"?  "NDB Cluster"?  Something else?

Comment: @RickJames I am quite a newbie when it comes to DB clusters, so I'm not sure of differences.  But I am leaning more towards master/slave replication instead as I research it. The master can be used by crawlers since it does most of the writing while the slave can power the public website. Although I guess the public  would need to use master at times too if it needs to write. Eventually, I could have another slave for statistical/analytical purposes. I will just need to research performance of master/slave replication.

Comment: You have a lot to learn.  Suggest you prototype the crawler and search engine with just a single (Master) server first.  This will give you some feel for what needs to be done.  Then re-do the topology to have some form of replication and/or clustering.  Keep reading; there advantages and disadvantages to each.  At the re-do time we can discuss what is best based on your experiences thus far.  By then you will know how much volume (reads, writes, data, etc) you can anticipate.  That data may influence the topology choices.

Comment: @RickJames I already have the crawler running on production/master setup right now. That's why I know I need a better solution as it causes performance issues for public users while it is running. For example, last time crawler was running, Mysql process was using 300% CPU and 30% memory. This is on a 4 CPU core Linode with 8 GB ram.

Answer (score 0):

Crawler:

- Put this process on a separate server (or multiple servers).
- If practical, use multi-row `INSERTs` to batch-insert the rows.
- See this for more tips on high-speed ingestion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table
- Write to the Master (or, if allowed by the cluster, any of the Masters).

For the web side:

- Have multiple servers with Apache / nginx / whatever receiving the requests.
- Send the requests to the Slave(s) (or nodes).
- Use round-robin (if there is more than one server for reading).

Other things:

- 300% CPU is high.  Let's see the worst offender, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.
- Your dataset will probably be very large, so shrink datatypes where practical, and normalize where appropriate.  (The above link has more on normalizing.)
- So far, a single Master seems to be adequate, hence any of the replication or clustering options is still viable.
- All writes are performed on all servers.  This puts a cap on how much you can scale.  The only way to go beyond that is via "sharding".
- Read scaling can be achieved by adding more Slaves, virtually without limit.  This applies to all flavors of replication/clustering.
- Indexing -- Use `FULLTEXT` for searching for "words"; use regular `INDEXes` where appropriate.
- Since neither `FULLTEXT` nor `INDEX` handles "model numbers" and "synonyms", you may need to sanitize the data *as it is inserted*.

Comment: Right now the crawler is a completely separate server that sends data in a POST request to a receiving back-end server, which at this time, is same as DB and public web server. The crawler server does not save directly to any database. I added more information in my original question in regards to how data is processed.

Comment: @zen - One simple way to get some scaling is to put separate functions on separate machines.  Also, if some things (like the public web server) become the bottleneck, you can have multiple servers providing that functionality.  I am not sure, but it seems like converting crawler info into a POST, then processing it, may be rather inefficient.  Another thing to consider:  having multiple crawlers.  (This would require some coordination so that they are not repeating each-other's work.)

Comment: The reason the crawler sends data in a POST request is because there's actually multiple crawlers on one server.  They do not run concurrently (although they technical could), And eventually, it could be on many different servers. So instead of various crawlers interacting with DB directly, it's easier to have one main point of contact with database that processes the data.  Otherwise, all that processing logic would have to be duplicated on every crawler server.